# Django re-usable Marketplace app

Tags: python, django, reusability

I'm working on initial phases of a site which has a typical [Freelance Marketplace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freelance_marketplace) model. It has buyers, sellers, transactions, payment gateway integration, ratings, dispute management etc.

Rather than creating everything from scratch, I was wondering if there is are any generic django apps which I can use as base and create on top of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the project lead for Django Market, production is at greatcoins.com and GitHub source code is at https://github.com/StephenPower/CollectorCity-Market-Place. You can download a VM image to download and test from the site.

Answer (score 3):

There is [django-marketplace](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-marketplace), [django-market](http://www.djangomarkethq.com/).

Comment: Have you personally used any of these? Seems like the first one is eventually a dead link while the second is geared towards online store.

Comment: Double check the second, it's for users to buy **and** sell.

Comment: down voted because none of these links are useful